# Somehow, I've stoped OpenGL working

Tags: opengl, mesa

Somehow, I can no longer run anything that uses OpenGL. Any attempts to do so get the error `Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".`.

In `/usr/lib` I have `LibGL.la`, `LibGL.so`, `LibGL.so.1` and `LibGL.so.325.15` (to which `LibGL.so` and `LibGL.so.1` symlink).

Can anyone figure out why it wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it (and there's no much to look at so I could be wrong) you're on a Nvidia system using the [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).

Even if you're not on that PPA, it seems possible that you've updated the Nvidia graphics driver recently and haven't yet rebooted. When you update the driver module it isn't automatically reloaded into the kernel. To do that you would need to shut down X, `rmmod` and `modprobe` for it (and in my experience that doesn't even work for the deb-installed Nvidia driver, only the manual install.

The fix is *really* simple though. Restart the computer.
Your computer should load the new copy of the Nvidia module on boot and then everything 3D should just work™ again.

---

As this is a Bumblebee-using computer, it might be enough to close anything using 3D then run:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

But as I say, this doesn't work on normal computers with the deb installer for the driver. Not sure why but it's worth a shot. Otherwise: reboot.

---

This might actually be far more TBP-related than I originally thought. Here is [a support thread suggesting that something needs renaming](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/ms1enaYkk4s).

I think the suggestion involves editing `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` so that
`KernelDriver=nvidia-current` and then running `sudo restart bumblebeed` to restart bumblebee.

Comment: I'm on nvidia but I'm using Bumblebee. Does that change anything? I have rebooted already.

Comment: @Gausie That's certainly an interesting twist. I've added a test you could try but if that doesn't work (and I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't), just reboot and see if that helps.

Comment: I've got `ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': No such device`

Comment: If rebooting hasn't helped, it may be a bug between the current version of TBP and the latest Nvidia driver.

Comment: I'm only using Nvidia 304. Hmm this is frustrating.

Comment: I'm going to reinstall - don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a

> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri

and it should work again.

Comment: It says its already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Remove ATI Drivers

sudo apt-get purge fglrx*

### 2. Move XOrg Server Configuration

sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf  /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak

### 3. Reinstall XOrg

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64

### 4. Reconfigure XOrg

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Comment: This is a nvidia setup.

Comment: Oli is correct. I've also got Bumblebee installed.